# Why is FinBert with Tensorflow showing different predictions on local computer vs on HuggingFace's web interface?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

To set the context, if i go to : https://huggingface.co/ProsusAI/finbert and input the following sentence on their hosted API form
`Stocks rallied and the British pound gained.`

I get the sentiment as 89.8% positive,6.7% neutral and the rest negative, which is as one would expect.

However if I download the tensorflow version of the model from :https://huggingface.co/ProsusAI/finbert/tree/main along with the respective Json files, and it run it locally I get the output as
`array([[0.2945392 , 0.4717328 , 0.23372805]]` which corresponds to a ~ 30% positive sentiment.

The code i am using locally is as follows ( modfin is the local folder where i have stored the t5_model.h5 alongwith the other files)

```
model = TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("C:/Users/Downloads/modfin",config="C:/Users/Downloads/modfin/config.json",num_labels=3)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("C:/Users/Downloads/modfin",config="C:/Users/Downloads/modfin/tokenizer_config.json")
inputs = tokenizer(sentences, padding = True, truncation = True, return_tensors='tf')
outputs = model(**inputs)
nn.softmax(outputs[0]).numpy()
```

for the model I also get a warning as follows

```
All model checkpoint layers were used when initializing TFBertForSequenceClassification.

Some layers of TFBertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at C:/Users/Downloads/modfin and are newly initialized: ['classifier']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
```

which is strange since I would assume a pre-trained model such as finbert should already be fine-tuned. when i replace `TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification` with `TFAutoModel` i see that the transofrmer that is chosen automatically is 'TFBertModel' whose output is 10 X768 tensor which i am not able to interpret into sentiment classes. any help here would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have low vram on your GPU? If yes, then it maybe due to insufficient vram size to load in all tensors/weights

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for contributing an answer. It is a bit short though, could you please [edit] it to contain a bit more information on how insufficient vRAM could cause this and especially on how to prevent it? See [answer].